# Adding named constrained mysqli with a variable reference table name

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a table with a named constrained, however it is not being created. I tracked the problem to be in this line:

```
CONSTRAINT $fk_post_id_lik FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES $posts (global_id)
```

where $posts is the name of a table created before. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Lots could be wrong. Have you tried echoing the resulting SQL statement? If so, have you tried it in phpAdmin or similar? What error message are you getting? If none, is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Turns out the table $posts was being created AFTER this one... silly mistake. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the table $posts was being created AFTER this one, for which, when this table was being created, it did not find the required table. Silly mistake.